# *ignore* How to check if an Array<String> contains an item that starts with a value

Tags: java, arrays

The app fetches data from a server. The data is returned in an Array. I need to check if one of the Array items starts with a value specified in the app. If it's possible without iterating because that slows down the app significantly.

Comment: It's very hard to see how the code you've shown corresponds to the code you quoted at the start - and *that* code just checks whether the array contains an *equal* element; it doesn't check whether any item in the array contains "lol". A short but complete example which genuinely demonstrates what you're interested in would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I'm sorry I'll check if right now!

Comment: If you don't know structure of data, you'll need iteration. If for example array is sorted, you can use binary search for speed-up.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I've changed my code

Comment: @tim687 `array["101"]`. Still doesn't compile.

Comment: @ChetanKinger sorry didn't saw that one, fixed now

Comment: It's *still* not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, is it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited the question, please look at comments of the answer below.

Comment: You've now edited the question to remove *all* code. That's still not as good as a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, is it? Note that "contains" isn't the same as "starts with". For "starts with" you could use an ordered list, and search it in O(log n) time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then I'm iterating trough all of the objects, and that's not what I want

Comment: No, you're not iterating through *all* of them. You'd do a binary search. You'd need it to be sorted first though, of course - which would be an O(n log n) step beforehand, but if you need to perform the "search" operation multiple times, you'd save time fairly quickly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to search with a String, is that possible to do with a binary search aswell? Or is there some other search method that allows this?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible - but *only* because you're looking for "starts with" rather than "contains" behaviour. If you'd made all this clear in your question, it wouldn't have been closed... it's *so* important to write clear questions. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank's I'll take a look at it next time I post a question. How do i check if it starts with without iterating?

Comment: How about you edit this question to be a *good* one, then it may be reopened, and I can *answer* it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just an array data structure, there is no way to check what it contains without actually looking into it.

However if you use a different data structure such as a HashMap (which is built on to of an array) you can check/lookup a key like `"101"` in O(1) time typically. You can check `map.isEmpty()` in O(1) time.

In short, if it's taking too long to perform a simple operation, chances are you need to be using a different data structure (or possibly more than one)

Comment: You actually mean that you can check whether an item in the hashmap contains a value without the two being completely equal?

Comment: @tim687 Good question. No there has to be an exact match. I guess this answer needs an update :)

Comment: @ChetanKinger That's the question that was trying to ask by starting this question :-p. Again sorry for not asking clear questions, I find it quite difficult to do so sometimes.  I hope that there is a convenient solution for this problem

Comment: @tim687 to do a fast lookup of part of a value you need to have an index of all possible lookups.